# Within a UICollectionViewCell, setRegion has no effect for a MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, mkmapview, uicollectionviewcell

I have set up a simple `MKMapView` (it is intended just to display a location on the map and nothing more) within one cell of a section of a `CollectionView` and am unable to set its region using `setRegion`.  The `MKMapViewDelegat`e is correctly set to the `UICollectionViewCell` as shown by breakpoints being hit within all the delegate methods.

I first tried to **set the region** in the View Controller's `cellForItemAtIndexPath` but I'm guessing this is too early, i.e. before the map is loaded so nothing happens and it loads a default location in the middle of the ocean.

I have tried passing the `CLCoordinateLocation2D` from the view controller to a `CLCoordinateLocation2D` in the cell during `cellForItemAtIndexPath` to set the region within the cell but where is the appropriate place to set the region?  In a `ViewController` it should be done in `ViewDidAppear` rather than ViewDidLoad or `ViewWillAppear` so that the map is loaded but I cannot find an equivalent event for a `collectionviewcell`.  `awakeFromNib` is clearly too soon.  I have tried using various mapView delegates such as:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1
regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta =  0.0025, .longitudeDelta =  0.0025};
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView1     regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coords, 200, 200)];
  [mapView1 setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
}
```

which runs but again does not change the region.  I have tried

```
- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView and
- (void)mapViewWillStartRenderingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView
```

which seemed the best bets but a breakpoint before and after the `setRegion` line shows the region is never updated to the region I'm setting it to.  The events all should be at a time that the map is fully loaded so why does `setRegion` simply have no effect??

**Cell h file:**

```
@interface BasicsCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coords;
@end
```

**Cell m file:**

```
@interface BasicsCollectionViewCell() <MKMapViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation BasicsCollectionViewCell
@synthesize mapView;
@synthesize coords;

 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1
regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta =  0.0025, .longitudeDelta =  0.0025};
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView1     regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coords, 200, 200)];
  [mapView1 setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
}
```

And the relevant part of `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

```
 cell0 = (BasicsCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BasicsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {.latitude = self.latitude, .longitude = self.longitude};
    [cell0 setCoords:coord];
    cell0.mapView.delegate = cell0;
    MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta =  0.0025, .longitudeDelta =  0.0025};
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [cell0.mapView regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 200, 200)];
    [cell0.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
    return cell0;
```

EDIT:

If I put breakpoints in the following code before and after the `setRegion` line at the asterixed points...

```
 - (void)mapViewWillStartRenderingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView
{
    MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta =  0.0025, .longitudeDelta =  0.0025};
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView     regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coords, 200, 200)];
  *****[mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
  *****}
```

then the debugger gives the following at the first breakpoint:

```
po self.mapView.region
 {
   (latitude = -41.508575000000008, longitude = 174.19921900000011)
   (latitudeDelta = 13.733789001832008, longitudeDelta = 59.305518116231042)
}
```

And the same at the breakpoint immediately after:

```
po self.mapView.region
 {
   (latitude = -41.508575000000008, longitude = 174.19921900000011)
   (latitudeDelta = 13.733789001832008, longitudeDelta = 59.305518116231042)
}
```

While at both breakpoints, the following is the (correct) value of `adjustedRegion:`

```
po adjustedRegion
     {
      (latitude = -0.13506928037132482, longitude = 51.518398284912109)
      (latitudeDelta = 0.0018087389042361623, longitudeDelta = 0.0058458603824931288)
    }
```

So it is simply that either `setRegion` is being ignored for some reason or it’s overridden by something else.  Any ideas which?

Comment: Log the value of `coord.latitude` and `coord.longitude` right after it is set in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.  By the way, calling `setRegion` _inside_ the region-changed delegate methods could lead to infinite recursion and stack overflow.  For your purposes, you should not be calling setRegion from those delegate methods.  Make sure the coordinate is set properly.

Comment: Hi Anna, it's correct there and is also correct at the later point that setRegion is run.  I'm aware of issues with the region-changed delegate code being there but I tried it as a last resort after spending so many hours trying to resolve this - before I was using mapViewWillStartRenderingMap.  I have edited my question to give some more useful info on the variable values. Hopefully that might help clarify

Comment: The coordinates -41.xxx,174.xxx are in the water near New Zealand.  The coordinates -0,51 are in the Indian Ocean.  You're also setting the region width to just 200 meters.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar one, where map region was not changed. So I manually called mapView delegate method

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
```

in `- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` of view controller.

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Manually called delegate method to forcefully set region.
    [self mapView:self.mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:YES];
}
```

In your case call this method right after when you set map region. From your above code for example in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method. For example:

```
cell0 = (BasicsCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BasicsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {.latitude = self.latitude, .longitude = self.longitude};
[cell0 setCoords:coord];
cell0.mapView.delegate = cell0;
MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta =  0.0025, .longitudeDelta =  0.0025};
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [cell0.mapView regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 200, 200)];
[cell0.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];

[cell0.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];

// Force call of delegate method
[self mapView:cell0.mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:YES];


return cell0;
```

Note:

Don't forgot to override `regionDidChangeAnimated` method in view controller.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
}
```